# How to override Moodle Core functionality?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

I would like to override the core functionality in *Moodle*. Just like we did on *Opencart* by writing its XML. is there any way to do that, Because I don't want to touch the core functionality.

Comment: @k for moodle ? ocmod? I did not get your answer

Comment: Oops sorry, It is wrong comment. I deleted it, please delete your also

Comment: There are lots of ways to override core Moodle functionality by writing plugins (particularly themes). Not everything can be overridden this way, however. You would have to be a lot more specific about exactly what you were trying to do, if you are wanting help with it.